# Goto not working correctly C++

Tags: c++, goto

I recently started learning c++, and I am just testing what I know by making a terrible little game.

I want to jump back in my code, so I learnt about a goto statment. Here is my code(not all of it, just the goto bit)

```
moving:

if(moveChoice == "Forward"){
    cout << "You moved Forward" << endl;
    moveChoice = "";
    if(firstTargetRand == 2){
        cout << "You encountered a tree!" << endl;
    }if(firstTargetRand != 2){
        cout << "goto init" << endl;
        goto moving;
    }
}
```

Now "goto moving" is getting called ( checked with cout goto init ) but this isn't working. I know this is prob a really stupid mistake, but I can't see anything wrong with it

Comment: With the amount of information presented, all I can tell you is you're wrong, `goto` is working fine. Couldn't tell you where you're wrong though without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: My top guess is that your `moveChoice` is of type `char*`. Change it to `std::string` to fix the first problem. The second problem would be to un-learn the `goto` ;-)

Comment: better yet would be to learn how to write code without goto's. they have very few valid usage cases, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: Sometimes debugging works. Often actually.

Comment: Whats so bad about goto's? And what would you suggest that I learnt/did instead? @dasblinkenlight moveChoice is a string :p

Comment: Add `cout << "now at moving label\n"` just below `moving:`. Whenever you then see "goto init" followed by "now at moving label", then that must mean that the `goto` jumped just fine.

Comment: `while (still_playing) { ... }`

Comment: @user3532547, `goto` is just about the easiest way to get spaghetti code if not used correctly. This code is a prime candidate for a loop.

Comment: @user3532547 If you would like to know what's wrong with `goto`, [this article](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: I would not try too hard learning to use a goto in c or c++. A goto is almost never needed and is usually bad practice / spaghetti code.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, I feel obligated to mention that goto is frowned upon for pretty much any use, and like the comments say, this is prime loop material.

Your problem is that you are checking if moveChoice == "Forward", then setting moveChoice to "", then going back, and then moveChoice == "Forward" always returns 0.

If you really want the goto, try this:

```
if(moveChoice == "Forward"){
    moving:
    cout << "You moved Forward" << endl;
    moveChoice = "";
    if(firstTargetRand == 2){
        cout << "You encountered a tree!" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "goto init" << endl;
        goto moving;
    }
}
```

If you aren't terribly partial to the goto, try this:

```
while(moveChoice=="Forward"){
    cout << "You moved Forward" << end1;
    if(firstTargetRand == 2){
        cout << "You encountered a tree!" << end1;
        moveChoice = "";
    }else{
        cout << "goto init" << end1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just fixed this another way(still using while though). However, this does look a lot better ^.^ thanks!

Comment: You did not remove `goto moving;` from the else{} in your while() example.